# Query on pointer to same class in parse

Tags: javascript, pointers, parse-platform

I have a subclass called TreeFolderObject. One of the column headings is called "parent" and is a pointer field. It points to other another object in the same class. Here is the stripped down code I am using to attempt to read data from this structure:

```js
        var TreeFolderObject = Parse.Object.extend('TreeFolderObject');
        var folderQuery = new Parse.Query(TreeFolderObject);
        folderQuery.include("parent");
        folderQuery.find().then(function(results) {
                for (i in results) {
                    treeData.push({
                        title: results[i].get('folderName'),
                        objectId: results[i].id,
                        parent: results[i].get("parent")
                    });
                    console.log(results[i].get("parent").get("folderName") );
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("failed, with error code: " + error);
            }
        );
```

The console line reports the following output:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

I have also tried shortening the console.log line to just:

```
console.log(results[i].get("parent") );
```

and this reports the following:

```
undefined
index.html:100 
ParseObjectSubclass {className: "TreeFolderObject", _objCount: 32, id: "oq5o2zFqIM"}

index.html:100 ParseObjectSubclass {className: "TreeFolderObject", _objCount: 24, id: "oq5o2zFqIM"}

index.html:100 ParseObjectSubclass {className: "TreeFolderObject", _objCount: 41, id: "oq5o2zFqIM"}


etc
```

This indicates that the browser client is obtaining the information I am after. I just can't work out how to get the data "out", if that makes sense.

Ultimately, I want to identify the parent object of each object so I can iterate through the class.

What I am doing wrong? I have tried searching here and on the web in general and there are a lot of very similar questions. This is obviously a confusing topic. I just can't work it out though and any help would be much appreciated. How do I get the console to print out the folderName property of the parent object?

Here's a screenshot of the parse control panel, if that helps:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t90m.png)

Comment: Can you post a picture of the class in the parse data browser, making sure to include the parent col heading?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to debug Parse cloud code sometimes, so I suggest putting superfluous console.logs() around, even if it's just incrementing numbers, so you can have a better idea of what line you're terminating at. You never got to console.log, it looks, so it never output anything. Henry is probably right, about needing the var in front of i. Either that, or double check that your column head is "parent" and not "Parent"

Answer (score 0):

Add "var" in front of i like this

```
    var TreeFolderObject = Parse.Object.extend('TreeFolderObject');
    var folderQuery = new Parse.Query(TreeFolderObject);
    folderQuery.include("parent");
    folderQuery.find().then(function(results) {
            for (var i in results) {
                treeData.push({
                    title: results[i].get('folderName'),
                    objectId: results[i].id,
                    parent: results[i].get("parent")
                });
                console.log(results[i].get("parent").get("folderName") );
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("failed, with error code: " + error);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Added var, as per your suggestion. Didn't make any difference, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

I eventually discovered the answer, and its got nothing to do with labeling i as a var, or the fact that I'm querying the same class. The solution is to put a condition line in the query. In other words, insert this after the first two lines of the code I posted earlier:

folderQuery.exists("parent");

In my case *every* object in the class, apart from one, has a parent, so this works fine. What I don't understand is why it should be necessary to put a condition on the query at all, if I'm intending to query the *entire* class.

I discovered the solution after browsing lots of parse pointer related questions on StackOverflow. No one else seems to have fallen into the exact same trap of leaving out the condition line, and eventually I realised that my parse query wasn't following the convention. If this realisation helps anyone else out there, I will be happy to have helped!

If anyone can help with an explanation as to why I need to put a condition line in, even though I'm querying the entire class, please let me know. In the meantime, I'm happy to have found this solution as it was holding up development of my project.